# printing values for x,y,and z in columns, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import xlrd
import os

path = 'data'

with open('', 'w') as f:
    column_values=['', '', '']

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if fullname.endswith('.xls'):
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fullname)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'')

            for j in range(0,sh.nrows):
                for ind in range(3):
                    column_values[ind] += ((', ' if column_values[ind] else '') +
                                           str(sh.cell(j,ind).value))


    # more reasonable format put lists one per row, x, y and z
    f.write('\n'.join(column_values)+'\n')
```

this script prints the values in the x values in the first row, y values in the second row, and the z values in the 3rd row. so how do i make it print he values in the first three columns?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's very, very basic programming. I would rewrite the script like this:

```
import xlrd
import os

path = 'E:\\IMRT_C\\Preanalysis\\'

with open('E:\\IMRT_C\\Working_files\\Trying_excel.csv', 'w') as f:
    column_values=[[], [], []]

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if fullname.endswith('.xls'):
            print('Handling %r' % filename)
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(fullname)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'RawTrackingData')

            for j in range(21,sh.nrows):
                for i in range(3):
                    column_values[i] += [str(sh.cell(j, i).value))]

    # more reasonable format put lists one per row, x, y and z
    for i in range(len(column_values[0])):
        for j in range(3):
             f.write(column_values[j][i] + (", " if j < 2 else "\n"))
```

I haven't tested this, but I hope it works.

Comment: thank you...it worked. i have another question...lets say i have 10 excels in a folder. all of the excel files represent a single patient. each excel files in the folder represent day of treatment for a the patient. each excel file has x, y, and z data. lets say if i want to print the x values for all of the excel files in a single folder...like first column would have day one of the x values, secound column would have day 2 of x values....and so on...

Comment: Then you would need to augment the creation of column_values. This is not hard since you have most of the needed stuff already in the script, but this would now turn into a "real" programming job for me. If you cannot do this yourself, you should ask someone to do it for you, or turn it into a bounty.